# Matlab parallel computing time effiency

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Currently I've started to work with matlab's parallel computing toolbox. I wanted to test it with a code for face recognition. My first try was with the Eigenfaces function using 10.000 images:

Script:

```
function [m, A, Eigenfaces] = EigenfaceCore(T)
tic
Train_Number = size(T,2);
A = [];  

for i = 1 : Train_Number
temp = double(T(:,i)) - m; 
A = [A temp,]; % Merging all centered images
end

L = A'*A;
[V D] = eig(L); 

x = zeros(1,size(D,1));
for i = 1 : size(D,1)
x (i) = D(i,i);
end

L_eig_vec = [];
for i = 1 : size(V,2) 
    if( x(i) > 1)
        L_eig_vec = [L_eig_vec V(:,i)];
    end
end

Eigenfaces = A * L_eig_vec; % A: centered image vectors
toc
```

For this code I need something that takes about 112 seconds.

If I open a POOL with 4 kernels, and use `parfor` instead of `for`, it takes 421 seconds. Can somebody help me? I thought by increasing the number of images (first it was something about 20 Images and parfor needing more time) the parallel computing version will pass the normal version.

Comment: Still nobody? Hmm I couldn't find a solution. Maybe use parallel computing for eig()?

Comment: Hi Kerem, I struggle to understand your use case. If I rephrase it, you would like to parallelize this function onto you four cores so you replaced all the for loops by parfor. Do you have some examples of input?
FYI, I am working for [ActiveEon](http://www.activeeon.com) which is providing a tool to distribute matlab functions as well, see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQi0aM3V2VQ).